# A finitely presented infinite group where every non-trivial element is conjugate to a power of a fixed element

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does there exist a non-abelian finitely presented infinite group $G,$ with a non-trivial element $y\in G$ such that every non-trivial element $x\in G$ is conjugate to some power of $y$?  More precisely, for every non-trivial $x\in G,$ there exists $z_{x}\in G$ such that $z_{x}xz_{x}^{-1}=y^{n}$ for some non-zero integer $n.$

This question arose in a symplectic geometry seminar in my department earlier this week as a (possibly vacuous) hypothesis on the fundamental group of a closed manifold, and of course a positive answer to this question would yield a closed manifold with this fundamental group.

Comment: at the risk of making a dumb comment are there some extra restrictions you want to add to rule out silly/trivial cases like ${\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: You're not dumb Yemon, I am.  I've edited to ask for a non-abelian group, although I think I'm being overly safe in imposing this condition.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There are no such known examples. Infinitely presented examples are known, but these are specially constructed.

Comment: Well, you shattered my dream of, surely Mark Sapir knows an example, which led me to ask this question on mathoverflow, but thank you for the expert information.

Comment: There's no reason to assume $x$ nontrivial and $n\neq 0$ (the case $x=1$ being trivial with $n=0$ and $n=0$ being excluded otherwise).